# UserManager<ApplicationUser>.Create() is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following code in the Seed method of my Configuration.cs file:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

IdentityResult result = manager.Create(new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "test@mail.com", Email = "test@mail.com", Name = "Martin Tracey" }, "password");
if (result.Succeeded) { Console.WriteLine("User created successfully"); }
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong. result is "+result.ToString());
    foreach (var error in result.Errors) Console.WriteLine(error); 
}
```

For whatever reason, the `manager.Create` call is returning `null`.

Any idea why this method would ever return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! It's a very simple solution.

My `userStore`variable didn't have a DbContext which would allow it to access and write to the Database. The simple solution is to use the context passed into the Seed method. Works like a charm now! See below:

```
protected override void Seed(MyFirstWebApplication.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    if( !context.Users.Any( u => u.Email == "test@mail.com" ) )
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "test@mail.com", Email = "test@mail.com", Name = "Martin Tracey" };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, "password");}
    }
}
```